# Grab array from div text to plot with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, web2py, chart.js

I'm new with programming, so please go easy if I'm not clear with my explanation...
In a Web2Py view I have a div with an id="convgraphdata" containing numbers that I would like to plot with ChartJS. The numbers vary depending on inputs but look like this: [4,6,7,3,20,46,...]. As I want to plot dynamic data, I would like have ChartJS pick up the text from within the div, convert it to an array, then plot the data in the array. I have tried so many ways to grab the data from the div and cant make it work.

For example, the ChartJS code is:

```
var lineChartData = {
    labels : days(),
    datasets : [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : convdata()
        }]}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
}
function days() {
    var days = []; 
    for (var i = 1; i <= 365; i++) {days.push(i);};
    return days;}
```

And the convdata() function is where I am having trouble. My code is:

```
function convdata() {
    var convdata = [];
    var data1 = document.getElementById("convgraphdata").textContent.slice(1, -1);
    var convdata = data1.split(",").map(Number);
    return convdata;}
```

I have tried numerous other methods too. The graph does not load whenever I include code to grab the text from a div. Not sure if this is helpful but the div contents are the result of an AJAX call in Web2Py. Web2Py likes to return the results to an HTML element, but if there is another way to send it direct to a ChartJS array, this could also work. Any help much appreciated.

Anthony, in response to your question, the full function is long and complicated so I will give a shortened explanation here... The javascript function picks up the data inside javascript user inputs then sends to the server using the Web2Py standard Ajax function in the format:

```
function conv_model(){
    ajax(['graph'],['select1', 'rate1', 'waittime1'], 'convgraphdata');}
```

The server-side function in python runs calculation on the data and returns the result to the client side div with id and name "convgraphdata". This data is what I want to graph in ChartJS.

Server side, the python function is in the format:

```
def graph():
# numerous calculations on user inputs
return dict(totalN=totalN)
```

There is also a view called graph.html which contains the code:

```
{{=totalN}}
```

Hope this is enough detail.

Comment: There is no need to have web2py write the Ajax results to a div (there are other options). Please show the Ajax call as well as the Python code that generates the response.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Web2Py likes to return the results to an HTML element

But that's just what the built-in ajax function does.

You can get always data from your controller with jQuery (bundled with web2py):

```
function getData() {
  $.ajax({
     url: "your_controller/get_data.json?", 
     data: { input1: "hello", input2: "bye"},
     success: function(result){
       //do what you want with result...
     }
  });
}
```

In the controller:

```
def get_data():
    response.view = 'generic.json'
    a = request.vars.input1
    b = request.vars.input2
    return {data: [1, 2, 4, 67]}
```

Comment: thanks for your idea, nicely described so I could easily understand. It could work but I also need to send users input data from javascript inputs to the server-side function get_data(). This is why I have been using the default Web2py ajax function,  ajax(['get_data'], ['input1', 'input2', ...], 'target'); Is it possible to  replace 'target' with the  function(result) into the standard Ajax function so that I can still send the inputs from the client to server side? Or is there another way to send the inputs in the ajax function you suggested?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to pass inputs in a basic way.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The code works to pass send the array to another javascript function. This was very helpful to show me how to do this, so thank you. Unfortunately ChartJS still does not want to recognise it. I have tested sending arrays from some javascript functions and it has worked okay, but I can't get it to update from the ajax result. At this time I have switched to Google Charts as it was much easier to graph the result of the ajax. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, if you're using GoogleCharts there is a web2py plugin that may help: http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1721/google-charts-plugin . Remember if the answer above is useful to you, consider accepting it to mark the question as answered.